# Basic Django Feeds

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner. I want to add a RSS function to my blog. It shows an RSS page but it shows no entries. I don't know why. My `urls.py` is:

```
feeds = {'latest': PostAtomFeed, }

...

url(r'^feeds/(?P<url>.*)/$', 'django.contrib.syndication.views.feed', {'feed_dict': feeds}),
```

And `feeds.py`:

```
from django.contrib.syndication.feeds import Feed
from myproject.myblog.models import Blog
from django.contrib.sites.models import get_current_site
from django.utils.feedgenerator import Atom1Feed

class PostRssFeed(Feed):
    title = "Run and Hide"
    description = "Latest Blog Entries"
    link = 'http://' + get_current_site(None).domain + '/blog/'

    def items(self):
        return Blog.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:10]

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.description

class PostAtomFeed(PostRssFeed):
    feed_type = Atom1Feed
    subtitle = PostRssFeed.description
```

My blog entry address is like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/1/`

But when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/feeds/latest/`, I get this:

[image: Screenshot]

I really don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you change the feed URL entry to `(r'^feeds/atom/$', PostAtomFeed()),`?

Comment: Hi Dominic, I changed the feed URL, it said TypeError at /feeds/atom/

__init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fix it!
I defined a wrong get_absolte_url() in my models.

Now, it works well.